# How to have privacy

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions

I am a teacher and would like to set up a site where students can save their work for me to view. The problem I have is that I would like one site but not allow the other students to view each others work. Is this easy to do as I have been having difficulty finding an efficient way of doing it.
Many thanks

Comment: How many students you have?

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution will be to create a Document Library and inside that folder for each student. Each student will have **Contribute** permission only in his/her Folder and will not have any permission on any other folder. Make your account as Site collection administrator, and give yourself **Full Control** permission in all of the student folders.

You can see this blog to see [How to break inheritance and set Folder level permissions](http://kimryan318.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/setting-permissions-on-folders-in-sharepoint-2010/) .

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint comes with security features for privacy. In your specific case if students are using Document Library to add their work then you can go to its Settings -> Advanced Settings and then set options for Read Access as "Read items that were created by the user".